# TSQL: Cannot perform an aggregate function AVG on COUNT(*) to find busiest hours of day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Consider a SQL Server table that holds log data. The important parts are:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerLog](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VisitDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The query here is around finding the distribution of visits **BY HOUR** of the day. We're interested in seeing the distribution of the *average number of visits for the **hour*** in a given date range.
 [image: Visits sample]

The query results would be something like this:

```
HourOfDay   Avg.Visits.In.Hour
0            24
1            16
5            32
6            89
7           823
etc.etc.
```

The intention is to write a query **like this**:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(hh, VisitDate)
        ,AVG(COUNT(*))    
FROM    CustomerLog
WHERE   VisitDate   BETWEEN 'Jan 1 2009' AND 'Aug 1 2009'
GROUP BY   DATEPART(hh, VisitDate)
```

This is not a valid query, however:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

**Question:** how would you re-write this query to gather the average totals (i.e. in place of `AVG(COUNT(*))` for the hour?

Imagine this query's results would be handed to a [PHB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-Haired_Boss) who wants to know what the **busiest hours of the day are**.

- SQL Server 2005+

Comment: You mean average number of visits in, say, the 10:00AM-11:00AM hour over the time span of X months?  Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: @Matthew, yes! I'll update the question to reflect the results desired.

Comment: One caveat - if on a given day for a given hour there are no visits, do you want the zero reflected in the average? Neither of the solutions so far covers this

Answer (score 7):

Using inline view:

```
SELECT DATEPART(hh, x.visitdate),
       AVG(x.num)
  FROM (SELECT t.visitdate,
               COUNT(*) 'num'
          FROM CUSTOMERLOG t
         WHERE t.visitdate BETWEEN 'Jan 1 2009' AND 'Aug 1 2009'
      GROUP BY t.visitdate) x
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, x.visitdate)
```

Using CTE (SQL Server 2005+) equivalent:

```
WITH visits AS (
   SELECT t.visitdate,
          COUNT(*) 'num'
     FROM CUSTOMERLOG t
    WHERE t.visitdate BETWEEN 'Jan 1 2009' AND 'Aug 1 2009'
 GROUP BY t.visitdate)
   SELECT DATEPART(hh, x.visitdate),
         AVG(x.num)
    FROM visits x
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, x.visitdate)
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies: In CTE version, You might actually want to return `DATEPART(hh, x.visitdate)` from CTE as something like `DATEPART(hh, x.visitdate) as VisitHour` so that it is converted only once within CTE.

Answer (score 0):

The number of days is known and it is equal to `DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(DATETIME,'2009.01.01',120),CONVERT(DATETIME,'2009.09.01',120))`. 
You have to calculate sum and divide it by number of days in selected range:

```
SELECT  
  DATEPART(hh, VisitDate),
  CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(DATETIME,'2009.01.01',120),CONVERT(DATETIME,'2009.09.01',120))
FROM CustomerLog
WHERE 
  (VisitDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'2009.01.01',120)) AND 
  (VisitDate < CONVERT(DATETIME,'2009.09.01',120))  
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, VisitDate)
```

`CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)` to have more precise result, but you can leave just `COUNT(*)` and have integer result.

If you use parameters, it will be:

```
SELECT  
  DATEPART(hh, VisitDate),
  CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / DATEDIFF(day,@beginningDate,@endDate)
FROM CustomerLog
WHERE 
  (VisitDate >= @beginningDate) AND 
  (VisitDate < @endDate)  
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, VisitDate)
```

If you want results for January, you have to use @beginningDate = '2009.01.01', @endDate = '2009.02.01'.