# Subquery having clause error, what am I missing?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

Why am I getting this error?

```
 SELECT        unitCode
        FROM            Enrolment
        WHERE        count(studentID) >
         (SELECT        AVG(Students) AS avgstudents
        FROM            (SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Students
       FROM            Enrolment AS Enrolment_1
        GROUP BY unitCode) AS a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's an extra paren at the end. I don't know much SQL so I couldn't say if there's anything wrong otherwise (or whether the paren is an issue at all).

Answer (score 1):

In where clause we can't use aggregate functions. You can use the count(studentID) function in HAVING clause.

Check this sample,

```
SELECT department, SUM(sales) as "Total sales"
FROM order_details
GROUP BY department
HAVING SUM(sales) > 1000;
```

Comment: Where would i put the having statement? In the subquery?

Comment: In the place of where cluse only u need to change that, not in subquery,     SELECT count(*), city
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY city
   HAVING count(*) =
    (SELECT max(count(*))
   FROM employee
   GROUP BY city);

Comment: Could you please update your code, so i can see it propely? (im using a mobile to view this site )

Comment: Just tell only u need to select unicode or need to select anyother data's with aggregated function like sum(),count(). Because we cant select without any aggregated func value in select if we are using having clause

Answer (score 0):

David check this,

```
select count(*),unicode from Enrolement 
    having count(StudentID) > (select avg(Students) ad avgstudents,unitCode
    from table_Name where Enrolement = "some of ur condtion"
    group by unitCode)
```

Need to change your query of the formatted syntax.. check your query businees accordingly.

Comment: Can you change my exact code in the first question to implement a having clause?

Comment: Can you change my WHERE        count(studentID) >
to a having statement so it works?

Comment: I just want to display the unitCodes that the values are higher than the avg(students) subquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select unitCode
from Enrolment
group by unitCode
having count(*) > (select avg(c.c) from (select count(*) as c from Enrolment group by unitCode) c);
```

With due deference to:

[TSQL: Cannot perform an aggregate function AVG on COUNT(*) to find busiest hours of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731093/tsql-cannot-perform-an-aggregate-function-avg-on-count-to-find-busiest-hours)